# Mean and Standard deviation of a histogram

Tags: c

Hi I am new to C programming and I am trying to work out the standard deviation and mean of a binned histogram containing numbers from 0.0 to 10.0 produced using the `rand()` function.

I don't seem to be getting the correct values back from the calculations. I have a feeling it's to do with the 
`h[i] = h[binNum]++;` line in my code but as i said i am new to this and would appreciate any help.

Here is what i have written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void){


float *x = {0};
int N = 1000;
int h[1000];
int i;
int binNum=0;
float mean;
float variance ;
float sd ;

x =(float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*N);


if (x == NULL){
   printf("Error no memory allocated");
   system("pause");
   return 1;

 } 


 for (i=0; i<1000 ;i++){

        h[i] = 0;

     }


for (i=0;i<N;i++){

    x[i]=rand()/3276.8;

}


for (i =0 ; i<N; i++){

    binNum = x[i]*100;
    h[i] = h[binNum]++;


}


for (i=0;i<1000;i++){

    mean  = mean + i * h[binNum];
}

    mean = mean/N;

    variance = 0;


for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
    variance = variance + h[i]*(i-mean)*(i-mean);

}
    variance = variance/(N-1);
    sd = sqrt(variance);

    printf("The Histogram mean is equal to %f\n",mean);
    printf("The standard Dev is equal to %f\n",sd);

    system("pause");
    free(x);
    return 0;   

}
```

Comment: *"I dont seem to be getting the correct values back from the calculations"*. Not good enough: You need to add input, output and expected output. Please read on how to provide [mcve], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please format/indent your code correctly.

Comment: Try to make a test example with a very small non random dataset ( (5 or 6 values instead of 1000).

Comment: Your formulas are either incorrect or horribly obfuscated. They don't look anywhere nere the correct formulas for mean, variance and std dev.

Comment: Your mean will be calculated as `(uninitialized value + 50500 * the last used h[binNum]) / 1000`, which does not make any sense.

Comment: It's pretty unusual to have as many bins as you do data .

Comment: Your program appears to assume that `RAND_MAX` is 32767 on your system.  That may hold for your particular system, but it is by no means a safe assumption in general.

Comment: This looks awfully suspicious: `h[i] = h[binNum]++;`.  I'm guessing you want only the right-hand side, not the assignment.

Comment: My primary suspect is `mean  = mean + i * h[binNum];`. Isn't binNum constant within that loop?